# Creating Forecast Record in salesforce

Tags: apex, forecast

I want to create a forecast record, but I am not able to create it. How do you use this object like others?

Answer (score 3):

Forecast records are created automatically as users create and modify opportunities and quotas. There is no need to create forecast records. You should look at the Forecasting tab's "Help for this page" for additional information.